# FieldValue.increment not working in offline in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have to increment a value in firebase firestore and the data is look like this

```
{
   "key":{
      "name":"Apple",
      "quantity":12
   }
}
```

I need to increment quantity by one. For this I use this Function.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      transaction.set(
          documentReference,
          {
            "key":{
              "quantity" : FieldValue.increment(1)
            }
          },
          SetOptions(merge: true));
      return transaction;
    });
```

This is working fine when the app is connected with network. But when the app goes offline, the value just increment by 1 when the app is connected again. Though several times `quantity` has increased in offline but it just increment by 1 when the connection is back.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a transaction for that, the way transactions work is by getting the current value of a field to determine the new value and the Firebase clients don't persist transactions across app restarts because the concept of transactions doesn't work well when a user is not connected.

Therefore the way transactions work makes it impossible for your current code to increment more than one time when offline. So in order to achieve what you want it would be better to take this out of a transaction/increment approach and possibly rethink the structure of your app to accomodate this counter in a different way, like a list of keys and a background function that gets the list when the app gets back online and increments it, for example.